# nested & repeated XML data to file or hive table using unix/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, pyspark

I am looking for help to convert more complex xml to file or hive table using unix or python scripting.

```
xml data is 
<FOLD name="ENTERTAINMENT" title="1">
<FOLD name="MOVIE1" title="2">
<EVNT_UNIX id="1234"  name="USA"/>
</FOLD>
</FOLD>
<FOLD name="MOVIE2" title="2">
<EVNT_UNIX id="12345"  name="INDIA"/>
<WORKS id='W123' name ='KRISH'/>
<WORKS id='W456' name ='Jhon'/>
<WORKS id='W789' name ='Nancy'/>
</FOLD>
<FOLD name="MOVIE3" title="4">
<EVNT_UNIX id="1234" name="INDIA"/>
<WORKS id='W123' name ='KRISH'/>
<FOLD name="MOVIE3-1" title="4">
<WORKS id='W456' name ='Jhon'/>
<LOCATION space='available' name ='TEST'/>
</FOLD>
</FOLD>
```

..

I have tried below sample code so far in phyton and getting only specific tag details irrespective of inner tag details.

```
doc = minidom.parse("test.xml")

foldlist = doc.getElementsByTagName("fold")
for fold in foldlist:
      fname = fold.getAttribute("name")
      title = fold.getElementsByTagName("title")
      print("fname:%s, title:%s" %
          (fname, title))
```

expected output is

```
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE1,1234,USA
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE2,12345,INDIA
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE2,w123,KRISH
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE2,w456,Jhon
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE2,W789,Nancy
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE3,1234,INDIA
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE3,W123,KRISH
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE3-1,4
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE3-1,W456,Jhon
ENTERTAINMENT,MOVIE3-1,available,TEST
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried belowcode so far and and able to get only one tag deatils(like grep/find in unix) doc = minidom.parse("test.xml")

# doc.getElementsByTagName returns NodeList
name = doc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
print(name.firstChild.data)

staffs = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff")
for staff in staffs:
        sid = staff.getAttribute("id")
        nickname = staff.getElementsByTagName("nickname")[0]
        salary = staff.getElementsByTagName("salary")[0]
        print("id:%s, nickname:%s, salary:%s" %
              (sid, nickname.firstChild.data, salary.firstChild.data))

Comment: put the codes into your question instead of one comment.

Comment: the above one s sample code.

Comment: updated my code details ..that i tried so far.